# Yii2 get data with join table

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I want to get all data from main table with left join relation with  its own conditions

**MainTableSearch.php**

```
class MainTableSearch extends MainTable
{
    public $table_two;
    public $table_three

    public function search($params)
    {
        $query = MainTable::find();

        $query->joinWith(['table_two']);
        $query->joinWith(['table_three']);

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);
....
```

**MainTable.php**

```
class MainTable extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'main_table';
    }  

    public function getTableTwo()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(TableTwo::className(), [main_id' => 'id'])->andWhere(['table_two.something' => 2]);
    }

    public function getTableThree()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(TableThree::className(), ['main_id' => 'id'])->andWhere(['table_three.something' => 2]);
    }
```

I want to see all data from main table in grid view and if table_two.something or table_three.something doesn't meet requirement to return null in that field.

I also tried

```
return $this->hasOne(TableThree::className(), ['main_id' => 'id'])->andWhere(['table_three.something' => 2])->orWhere(['table_three.something' => NULL]);
```

Comment: you have error when using  search function ?

Comment: no, some data from main table doesn't have correlations with table_two or table_three and that data doesn't show in grid view i want to see them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED]

```
    $query->leftJoin('table_two','main_table.id = table_two.main_id 
AND (table_two.something=1 OR table_two.something IS NULL)');
```

Comment: You don't want to use "=NULL", this is always false in databases (in contrast to programming languages). You want "IS NULL" instead.